# Python markdown footnote backlink text change

Tags: python

I am facing a very simple problem on changing the backref text in python footnote. I read the doc of footnote at [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/footnotes.html) . The site clearly says **BACKLINK_TEXT** could be overwritten to allow other character.

So I tried following code:

```
import markdown.extensions.footnotes
import markdown
markdown.markdown(some_text,extensions=['footnotes'], BACKLINK_TEXT ="&#916;")
```

The above code doesn't produce the Backref text specified as ← but gave the default value as ↩ . 
Is above code the correct way of initializing the config for footnote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading documentation about extensions I think you need

```
extensions=['footnotes(BACKLINK_TEXT=&#916)']
```

because `BACKLINK_TEXT` is option for `footnotes` extension.

See: [Markdown#extensions](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html#extensions)

Comment: This works too, but I figured there is error in python-markdown also. If you check class FootnoteExtension in footnotes.py , you can see they have error which I have answered above myself.

Comment: @Sarvagya Pant I put `print configs` in that file and I get `[(u'BACKLINK_TEXT', u'&#916')]` when I use `extensions=['footnotes(BACKLINK_TEXT=&#916)']` but I get empty list `[]` when I use `extensions=['footnotes'], BACKLINK_TEXT ="&#916;"` - so there is no mistake in code - only you expect too much using `extensions=['footnotes'], BACKLINK_TEXT ="&#916;"` :)

Comment: furas, your code worked too, but I was expecting to remove footnote by using BACKLINK_TEXT as "". The code you provided did so, but there was also a link that could point to the footnote area in text. Also if you look at FootnoteExtension class inside footnotes.py in markdown, you can see error in for key,val in configs. The line should have configs.iteritems(). They had missed it.

Comment: They didn't miss `iteritems()` because `configs` is not dictionary (which needs  `iteritems()`) but list of tuples like this `[(u'BACKLINK_TEXT', u'&#916')]` (which don't have `iteritems()`)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, there is error in footnotes.py code of python-markdown. They have used

```
for key,val in configs:
```

instead of:

```
for key,val in configs.iteritems().
```

This was the problem. Hope they fix this in another version.